# Unity 3d collision detection

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision-detection

I've been tearing my hair out for weeks just trying to detect a collision between a RigidBody and a BoxCollider tied to a spot light that is tied to the camera, I want to detect when the player is flashing their flashlight at something, but for some reason this doesn't work.

I don't think it's detecting the collision at all, the variable "test" does not change and nothing appears in console, the flashlight hitbox I'm sure is large enough, but the console still gives no indication of anything happening, I was following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QRp4V1JTZnM

and here's the simple code I made:

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col) {
    if (col.gameObject.name == "Spot_Light") {
        Debug.Log("detected");
        test = 375;
    }
}
```

Comment: How does your box collider work in relation to the flashlight? Are you able to get any collisions with the collider?

Comment: what collider your flashlight is using?

Comment: How are you moving your objects? Is there at least one Rigidbody involved? Do both objects have colliders that are **not** `isTrigger`? Is the name correct?

Comment: The flashlight has a box collider marked as "is trigger" extending outwards, and the object I have this code tied to has a rigid body, but no box collider, should I give it a collider of some sort?

Comment: I am completely sure the name has nothing to do with it, I've tried renaming the object, setting it to a letter so there's no confusion, and many more.

Comment: @Yablu if the box collider is marked as `isTrigger` it wont call  `OnCollisionEnter`! Use `OnTriggerEnter` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you marked trigger in your collider, you cannot use the `OnCollisonEnter` to detect a collison, you should use the `OnTriggerEnter` instead.